# Is a tree structure possible in Mathematica?

Tags: data-structures, trees

Let's say I have a vector,

```
vector={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
```

and I want to use its items as leaf nodes in a tree datasctructure, then work with them as such, adding new nodes by summing/multiplying etc. the leaf nodes (for example, make a parent node for nodes 1 and 2, which would be a sum of them (3)), then sum/multiply the new nodes etc. (for example, take the new parent nodes of 1,2 and 5,6, and make a parent node for them, which would be a sum of all 4 (14).

How would I go into creating a tree datastructure like this?

Comment: I think a lot more explanation is needed here.

Comment: I added some examples, hope it's a bit more clear now.

Comment: @Vojtevo If you are familiar with [Algebraic Data Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type), Mathematica expressions are general enough to represent sum and product types, e.g. for sum types you just use a different head, like `Node[]`/`Leaf[leafvalue]` or `Branch[]` and for product types like in a binary tree, just give more than one argument to your expression, e.g. `Branch[Leaf[1],Branch[Leaf[2],Leaf[3]]]` to represent arbitrary tree structures. You then use pattern matching and custom functions to create and modify your trees. Use `TreeForm[mytreeexpression]` to visualize.

Comment: See https://thinkmeta.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/mathematica-algebraic-data-types/ for an example of how you can build ADTs for sum and product types. I think some of the boilerplate there can actually be simplified, e.g. you don't need the wrapper `VertexT`